# Django: Why do I have to import signals in my AppConfig (it seems to work without)

Tags: python, django

I currently create a recurring cron job called every six hours via `python manage.py dynamic_pricing_adjustment`. As expected my console prints `DO STUFF`.

My **AppConfig**.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PricingConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myproject.pricing'
```

It says in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver) I should add it to the ready function. It seems to work without. Can you tell me what that part is for or why I should anyway add it?

```
def ready(self):
    from . import signals  # noqa
```

Here the rest of my code:

**dynamic_pricing_adjustment.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myproject.pricing.signals import dynamic_pricing


    class Command(BaseCommand):
        help = "Adjust prices for dynamic pricing"

        def handle(self, *args, **options):
            dynamic_pricing.send(self)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.dispatch import Signal, receiver

dynamic_pricing = Signal()


@receiver(signal=dynamic_pricing)
def adjust_prices(sender, **kwargs):
    print("DO STUFF")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, signals are used for predefined signals called by models (before/after save, delete etc) or Request (request started/finished). Django needs to know where your receiver functions live and register them. That is the reason why you import them in `AppConfig.ready()`. Otherwise they won't be runned.

In your case, you defined the custom signal and you called directly. In this example signals does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I will not use it as Signal in that case.